# caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: loops, variables

I can't figure out where I went wrong I keep getting the same error, I already defined i with let but it keeps saying I haven't defined i I am lost, I am very new to coding.

```
import { films } from '../data/films.js'
console.log(films[0].url)
function getLastNumber(url) {
const secondToLastLetterOfUrl = url[url.length - 2]
return secondToLastLetterOfUrl
let filmList = document.querySelector('#filmlist') 
for (let i = 0; i < films.length; i++) { }
let figure = document.createElement('figure')
let figImage = document.createElement('img')
let figCaption = document.createElement('figcaption')
let filmNum = getLastNumber(films[i].url)
figImage.src = `https://starwars-visualguide.com/assets/img/films/${filmNum}.jpg`
figCaption.textContent = films[i].title
figure.appendChild(figImage)
figure.appendChild(figCaption)
filmList.appendChild(figure)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1. `getLastNumber` is missing the closing curly brace. It probably would go after the return.
2. The for loop is empty. The scope of `i` is limited to the for loop, so when you try to access `i` four lines later, it is undefined. You probably want to move the closing curly bracket of the for loop after `filmList.append(figure)` line.